# JS sumselect не работает при смене подключения файла

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть библиотека sumselect.

```
<ol border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  id="selectable" align="center">
                                <li class="ui-state-default" vid=1>1</li>
                                <li class="ui-state-default" vid=2>2</li>
                                <li class="ui-state-default" vid=3>3</li>
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/datapik.js"></script>
```

имею такой код .  так все работает. но при попытке вынести подключение фаила в низ  ломается.  не понимаю в чем может быть проблема .Подскажите  мб кто сталкивался

Comment: Было бы неплохо уточнить, возможно есть текст ошибки в консоли браузера. Возможно у вас несколько файлов js зависимы друг от друга и они должны грузится в определенном порядке, который вы нарушили перенеся скрипт вниз.

Comment: @AmirOFF Мне кажется ты пытаешься работать с методами библиотеки до их подключения.

Comment: Сеичас увидел  такую логику . библеотека  толи  
    jquery.sumoselect.min.js толи  bootstrap-select. берет мой код . который выше и переделывает его в дивы. добавляя свой классы и тд . и видимо когда она его вставляет  заного (  тогда  скрип вновь грузиться )  получается  если  я выношу скрипт из блока . то он не регрузиться повторно  и новый  html  не виден для  js   вопрос  как это решить  перезагружать js ?

Comment: т е строиться дум потом  грузится  js   и если  после полной загрузки  js  зделать  изменения  напрмер добавить новый блок. то  js его уже не увидит как такие моменты решать?  не перезагружать же весь js

Comment: Для одного кастыля  нужно еше 10 подлорок получается ?

Comment: Решил пока так.  при  клике на  блок  делаю перезагрузку кода.
         var script = document.createElement('script');
         script.src = "my.js";
         document.body.appendChild(script);
Вопросы выше остаются актуальны. Всем спасибо